# Nginx proxy form Mattermost

Tags: forms, nginx, proxy, mattermost

the goal is that i have to configure nginx as a proxy to mattermost, so by typing :

"curl http://domain_name " i must have the page of mattermost, but what i have is the page of nginx

by putting this command : "curl http://domain_name:8065"

i have this error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to port 8065: Connection refused

here is my nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
                                     ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
        ;
}
`
```

ahd here the /etc/nginx/sites-available/mattermost

```
`upstream backend {
   server 41.231.54.146:8065;
   keepalive 32;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mattermost_cache:10m max_size=3g inactive=120m use_temp_path=off;

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name    mm.safozi.cloud;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name    mm.safozi.cloud;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mm.safozi.cloud/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mm.safozi.cloud/privkey.pem;
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
   # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
   # OCSP Stapling ---
   # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;

   location ~ /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket$ {
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       client_max_body_size 50M;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
       proxy_buffers 256 16k;
  client_body_timeout 60;
       send_timeout 300;
       lingering_timeout 5;
       proxy_connect_timeout 90;
       proxy_send_timeout 300;
       proxy_read_timeout 90s;
       proxy_pass http://backend;
   }

   location / {
       client_max_body_size 50M;
       proxy_set_header Connection "";
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
       proxy_buffers 256 16k;
       proxy_buffer_size 16k;
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;
       proxy_cache mattermost_cache;
       proxy_cache_revalidate on;
       proxy_cache_min_uses 2;
       proxy_cache_use_stale timeout;
       proxy_cache_lock on;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}

and this /opt/mattermost/config/config.json

{
    "ServiceSettings": {
        "SiteURL": "https://mm.safozi.cloud",
        "WebsocketURL": "",
        "LicenseFileLocation": "",
        "ListenAddress": "8065",
        "ConnectionSecurity": "TLS",
        "TLSCertFile": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mm.safozi.cloud/fullchain.pem",
        "TLSKeyFile": " /etc/letsencrypt/live/mm.safozi.cloud/privkey.pem",
        "TLSMinVer": "1.2",
        "TLSStrictTransport": false,
        "TLSStrictTransportMaxAge": 63072000,
        "TLSOverwriteCiphers": [],
        "UseLetsEncrypt": true,
        "LetsEncryptCertificateCacheFile": "./config/letsencrypt.cache",
        "Forward80To443": true,
        "TrustedProxyIPHeader": [
            "X-Forwarded-For",
            "X-Real-IP"
        ],
        "ReadTimeout": 300,
        "WriteTimeout": 300,
        "MaximumLoginAttempts": 10,
        "GoroutineHealthThreshold": -1,
        "GoogleDeveloperKey": "",
        "EnableOAuthServiceProvider": false,
        "EnableIncomingWebhooks": true,
        "EnableOutgoingWebhooks": true,
        "EnableCommands": true,
        "EnableOnlyAdminIntegrations": true,
        "EnablePostUsernameOverride": false,
        "EnablePostIconOverride": false,
        "EnableLinkPreviews": false,
        "EnableTesting": false,
        "EnableDeveloper": false,
        "EnableSecurityFixAlert": true,
        "EnableInsecureOutgoingConnections": false,
        "AllowedUntrustedInternalConnections": "",
        "EnableMultifactorAuthentication": false,
        "EnforceMultifactorAuthentication": false,
        "EnableUserAccessTokens": false,
        "AllowCorsFrom": "mm.safozi.cloud:443",
        "CorsExposedHeaders": "",
  "CorsAllowCredentials": false,
        "CorsDebug": false,
        "AllowCookiesForSubdomains": false,
        "SessionLengthWebInDays": 180,
        "SessionLengthMobileInDays": 180,
        "SessionLengthSSOInDays": 30,
        "SessionCacheInMinutes": 10,
        "SessionIdleTimeoutInMinutes": 43200,
        "WebsocketSecurePort": 443,
        "WebsocketPort": 80,
        "WebserverMode": "gzip",
        "EnableCustomEmoji": false,
        "EnableEmojiPicker": true,
        "EnableGifPicker": false,
        "GfycatApiKey": "2_KtH_W5",
        "GfycatApiSecret": "3wLVZPiswc3DnaiaFoLkDvB4X0IV6CpMkj4tf2inJRsBY6-FnkT08zGmppWFgeof",
        "RestrictCustomEmojiCreation": "all",
        "RestrictPostDelete": "all",
        "AllowEditPost": "always",
        "PostEditTimeLimit": -1,
        "TimeBetweenUserTypingUpdatesMilliseconds": 5000,
        "EnablePostSearch": true,
        "MinimumHashtagLength": 3,
        "EnableUserTypingMessages": true,
        "EnableChannelViewedMessages": true,
        "EnableUserStatuses": true,
        "ExperimentalEnableAuthenticationTransfer": true,
        "ClusterLogTimeoutMilliseconds": 2000,
        "CloseUnusedDirectMessages": false,
        "EnablePreviewFeatures": true,
        "EnableTutorial": true,
        "ExperimentalEnableDefaultChannelLeaveJoinMessages": true,
        "ExperimentalGroupUnreadChannels": "disabled",
        "ExperimentalChannelOrganization": false,
        "ImageProxyType": "",
        "ImageProxyURL": "",
        "ImageProxyOptions": "",
        "EnableAPITeamDeletion": false,
 "EnableAPITeamDeletion": false,
        "ExperimentalEnableHardenedMode": false,
        "DisableLegacyMFA": true,
        "ExperimentalStrictCSRFEnforcement": false,
        "EnableEmailInvitations": false,
        "ExperimentalLdapGroupSync": false,
        "DisableBotsWhenOwnerIsDeactivated": true,
        "EnableBotAccountCreation": false
    },
    "TeamSettings": {
        "SiteName": "SAFOZI Team Collaboration",
        "MaxUsersPerTeam": 50,
        "EnableTeamCreation": true,
        "EnableUserCreation": true,
        "EnableOpenServer": false,
        "EnableUserDeactivation": false,
        "RestrictCreationToDomains": "",
        "EnableCustomBrand": false,
        "CustomBrandText": "",
        "CustomDescriptionText": "",
        "RestrictDirectMessage": "any",
        "RestrictTeamInvite": "all",
        "RestrictPublicChannelManagement": "all",
        "RestrictPrivateChannelManagement": "all",
        "RestrictPublicChannelCreation": "all",
        "RestrictPrivateChannelCreation": "all",
        "RestrictPublicChannelDeletion": "all",
        "RestrictPrivateChannelDeletion": "all",
        "RestrictPrivateChannelManageMembers": "all",
        "EnableXToLeaveChannelsFromLHS": false,
        "UserStatusAwayTimeout": 300,
        "MaxChannelsPerTeam": 2000,
        "MaxNotificationsPerChannel": 1000000,
        "EnableConfirmNotificationsToChannel": true,
        "TeammateNameDisplay": "username",
        "ExperimentalViewArchivedChannels": false,
        "ExperimentalEnableAutomaticReplies": false,
        "ExperimentalHideTownSquareinLHS": false,
        "ExperimentalTownSquareIsReadOnly": false,
        "ExperimentalPrimaryTeam": "",
        "ExperimentalDefaultChannels": []
    },
    "ClientRequirements": {
     "AndroidLatestVersion": "",
        "AndroidMinVersion": "",
        "DesktopLatestVersion": "",
        "DesktopMinVersion": "",
        "IosLatestVersion": "",
        "IosMinVersion": ""
    },
```

Comment: What is the domain name you are using to curl the mattermost application? Also, I may be wrong, but from your mattermost json config it seems like you have already set up TLS termination there. While in your nginx virtual host you refer to the http version of your backend. Is the remote mattermost instance also up? For me it appears to be down (on that port)

Comment: As a sidenote, it is indeed good that you added HSTS, but beware of it at first. If you mess up once, you could mess up any browser that got the wrong rules. Kinda similar to how eg a bad 301 Permanent Redirect can stay and break your future redirecting

Comment: thanks for your replie
1-the domain name is `mm.safozi.cloud`
2- in nginx virtual host i refer to the http shoult that mean that in  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mattermost`  i should delete the `server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        . . .
}`
and keep just the ssl config ?
`server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;`

*for nginx log here the error

`*26 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 212.83.146.233, server: mm.safozi.cloud, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://41.231.54.146:8065/", host: "mm.safozi.cloud"
`

Comment: can you please tell me what should i do exactly cause im really stuck and im not understanding this issue, i dont know if its a problem with the ssl or if it's a problem of a redirect port, if it is how can i redirect nginx that have the port "80" to mattermost with the port "8065". is this what we mean by 'configuring nginx as a proxy for mattermost?" is it just a port redirect?? and how can i do that
Thank you so much for your time ^^

Comment: and how can i verifi  the remote mattermost instance if its up or not

Comment: and when i put the domain name in the url: https://mm.safozi.cloud. i receive "bad atway 502" i want the initial page of mattermost display when i put my domain.
what can i do !